# Helm always generates new secret values although they already exists in lookup

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to figure out why Helm upgrade always create new secret cookie when it is configured to not so if the secret with the value already exists in the deployment.

I have the following template function defined in my library chart:

```yaml
{{ include "my-lib.messaging.secrets" ( dict "global" .Values.global "messagingService" .Values "release" .Release ) }}
*/}}
{{- define "my-lib.messaging.secrets" -}}
{{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .release.Namespace "messaging-secret") | default dict }}
{{- if .global.config.enabled }}
  {{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .release.Namespace "global-secret") | default dict }}
{{- end }}
{{- $secretData := (get $secretObj "data") | default dict }}
{{- $cookie := (get $secretData "messaging.cookie") | default (randAlphaNum 32) }}
messaging.cookie: "{{ $cookie }}"
{{- end }}
```

The expectation here is that if the `messaging-secret` (or `global-secret`) exists and contains `messaging.cookie`, it will not be changes, the same value will be used, otherwise, new one will be generated.

When I install the chart, I get the following content of `global-secret`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  messaging.cookie: cXJSS2N6TDB2VGF4bzR4YWhEVzVuVXB2dzZMbWFzSWg=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-07T18:43:33Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: global-secret
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "18494964"
  uid: 3701e400-697c-48de-8eb9-c695ae624542
type: Opaque
```

But when I do the Helm upgrade, new value is generated, although it should not:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  messaging.cookie: Mk5DbThHRDRlSGRVNG1XQWZyTGJVSENtZWlWRGhvR3Y=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-07T18:43:33Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: global-secret
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "18495726"
  uid: 3701e400-697c-48de-8eb9-c695ae624542
type: Opaque
```

The Helm values contains:

```yaml
global:
  config:
    enabled: true
```

And the `global-secret.yaml` template contains the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: global-secret
stringData:
  {{- include "my-lib.messaging.secrets" (dict "global" .Values.global "messagingService" .Values.messagingService "release" .Release) | indent 2 }}
```

I would assume that the `lookup` will properly identify data and will use it, not generating new random value. Can someone advise where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many options to make it work, it was a silly mistake :D
The `secretObj` variable was simply not overwritten using `global-secret`, because of `:` in the second assignment. Therefore, the Helm was not able to use new value and it was null.

Solution, do no declare the same variable, use existing, meaning instead:

```yaml
{{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .release.Namespace "messaging-secret") | default dict }}
{{- if .global.config.enabled }}
  {{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .release.Namespace "global-secret") | default dict }}
{{- end }}
```

It should be:

```yaml
{{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .release.Namespace "messaging-secret") | default dict }}
{{- if .global.config.enabled }}
  {{- $secretObj = (lookup "v1" "Secret" .release.Namespace "global-secret") | default dict }}
{{- end }}
```

Eventually, quite simple fix!